# Storing active class in local storage when using bootstrap 4 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, bootstrap-4

I am having some trouble with the tab list below:

```
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="{$PageUrl}" role="tab">View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{$PageUrl}?action=edit" role="tab">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=diff" role="tab">History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=print" role="tab">Print</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=attr" role="tab">Attributes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#fat2" role="tab">@fat</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#mdo2" role="tab">@mdo</a>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Everything displays fine but this differs from how a lot of people implement tabs. Most examples i see have 'tab-content' and that shows the content for each tab. In my case i am using tabs to link alternate pages all together. This is where my issue comes in, When clicking on 'Edit' tab it does indeed load the edit page but with the active class or the 'View' tab still active. I cannot get the active class to switch between the tabs. I think this is because the page is reloading therefore eliminating the active data and setting it to default. How can I get around this and have it show the correct active tab after the newly selected page loads? Thanks for any help!

Edit:

Previously I was trying to use this at the bottom of my body with no luck:

```
$(function(){
var current = location.pathname;
$('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // if the current path is like this link, make it active
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
})
```

})

Comment: I think you want the complicated way. If I got it right, you are reloading the whole page with a new tab's content, and you want to make it active as well. Right? If the code in `{$PageUrl}` is generating this html snippet as well, you should generate the `active` class for the proper tab accordingly. Even if you are calling some other serverside code to do this, you should pass this information to that part of the code.

Comment: Ok, got it, you can't (don't want to) change server side code. I don't know that cms. Question: how does your browsers address bar looks like after you press _Edit_ for example? Still contains `?action=edit` query parameter (does it use redirect)?

Comment: It just appends the current URL so there is no redirection. ?action=edit is in the url. Changing the server side code is something I looked into and was lost. I know there is away to do it with jQuery but after many failed attempts I've come here for help.

Comment: Then here is a solution: 1) don't add `active` to your snippet. 2) add an event handler to page load (or a script simply at the end of the page) which checks the action value and adds the `active` class to the propet element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="default nav-link" href="{$PageUrl}" role="tab">View</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="edit nav-link" href="{$PageUrl}?action=edit" role="tab">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="diff nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=diff" role="tab">History</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="print nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=print" role="tab">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="attr nav-link"  href="{$PageUrl}?action=attr" role="tab">Attributes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2">
            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#fat2" role="tab">@fat</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#mdo2" role="tab">@mdo</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(function() {
    var action = (location.search.match(/(\^?|&)action=(.*?)($|&)/i) || [])[2]
    if(action) {
        $('a.nav-link.'+action).addClass('active')
    } else {
        $('a.nav-link.default').addClass('active')
    }
})
</script>
```

1. Does not add `active` class to any of the tabs by default.
2. All tab links have their action as class, to make it easy
3. On load it thecks the query in the window's address, and sets the active class accordingly

Comment: This is confirmed to be working. I appreciate the help!